# How to get the JSP page name which invoked the servlet from inside servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have many JSP pages and all of them invoke the same servlet.

Is it possible to get the JSP page name which invoked the servlet from inside that servlet?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It looks like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Servlet is a server-side controller whose `doGet` or `doPost` method gets invoked from `service` method every time when request's URL matches the servlet's url-pattern, as defined in web.xml, or via the usage of annotations.

That said, servlet **isn't** and *shouldn't* be aware of the HTML element that called it by sending a HTTP request, just like clicking on a link yields the same result independently of the `<a>` element that triggered it.

Of course, you can pass that information as a request parameter and later retrieve that information in servlet's methods by calling `request.getParameter("name")`, where request is `HttpServletRequest` and `name` is parameter name that describes the sender URL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want.

JSPs don't invoke Servlets directly (although, under the hood, they *are* servlets).

You should map URLs to Servlets in your web.xml, and then forward the response to JSPs from within the Servlet.
If you want the request URL,  use request.getRequestURL();

If you want the request parameters, use request.getParameter("name");

To forward to JSP:

```
String nextJSP = "/searchResults.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```